# View Controller hides after showing when called from ActionSheet manually

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am writing a code, where another view controller is called from Action Sheet. I am using "performSegueWithIdentifier" for this because I want to pass different text depending on which action button is pressed. It was working fine but now as I call the view controller from Action sheet, it appears and then hides suddenly. I checked my code but can't figure out the bug. Here is my code. Note: I am not using navigation controller.

```
//"selectEditor" is the button action used for calling action sheet. 
- (IBAction)selectEditor:(id)sender {

_sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select type of Editor"
                                     delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                       destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"Button1",@"Button2", nil];
[_sheet showInView:self.view];
} 

//Perform segue to vc when action button is pressed. "editorSegue" is segue identifier.
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
//trigger call here
    if (buttonIndex==0)
    {
        EditorFlag=1;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"editorSegue" sender:self];
    }

    if (buttonIndex==1)
    {
        EditorFlag=0;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"editorSegue" sender:self];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"editorSegue"]) {

    //Additional code here. EditorFlag is used for identification to set different text on same view controller when different action buttons are pressed.
    if (EditorFlag==1)
    {
        //EditTextController is the view controller which hides after showing
        EditTextController *textEditor = [segue destinationViewController];
        textEditor.textstring=@"some text";
    }
    else
    {
        EditTextController *textEditor = [segue destinationViewController];
        textEditor.textstring=@"some text";
    }
}
}

//Here is Editor text code, I am adding navigation bar manually but I also checked it by commenting all code in it.

@implementation EditTextController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
navBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:navBar];

UIBarButtonItem *doneItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(back:)];

UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:_navString];
[navItem setLeftBarButtonItem:doneItem animated:YES];

UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cloud_Arrow_Up.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(methodAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

[navBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem] animated:YES];
[self.textEditor setText:self.textstring];
_textEditor.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:24];
_textEditor.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

}

-(void)back:(id)sender
{
//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"realTimeSegue" sender:sender];
}

- (void)methodAction:(UIButton *)button
{
//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"syncSegue" sender:button];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: When you say, the view controller disappears, you actually see it's view disappearing. Show EditTexrController's code.

Comment: Yes. Okay, I will it above.

Comment: Is it related to segue connection? I created another view controller with nothing in it but results remains same.

Comment: My need is to push the "text" in calling view controller. Is their any other method to push the text without "prepareForSegue". I think, that will solve the problem.

Comment: I doubt that changing a method of pushing the text will resolve your problem. I don't see anything in your code that would cause the behaviour you described. What's the type of segue: push or modal? How exactly text editor disappears: animatedly, like when view controller pops out, or it just suddenly disappears? Full code of the view controller that displays text editor could help, perhaps. And I would recommend UIAlertController instead of UIActionSheet, if you don't have to support iOS 7.0, of course.

Comment: It animates. Okay, I will try to use UIAlertController because I am using iOS8. The segue I am using is push. This is the full code, I pasted. But if you help me in using another method for pushing the text without using "prepareForSegue". That will also help me. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to have nothing to do with Swift.  Please don't add inappropriate tags.